# Java and Hive : launch hql script

Tags: java, hive, hiveql

I have some HiveQL scripts which are stored into .hql file.

What is the best way to execute these scripts on Hive server with a Java/JDBC program?

Answer (score 0):

Use JDBC Hive Client.

```
Example, "jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default".
```

Currently, the only dbname supported is "default". Please see [JDBChiveclient](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hiveclient.html) link for detail.

Other way:**You can run it through shell script as well.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i have to use it in a Java program.

Comment: Please see the link which I have mentioned above.

Comment: I have already see this link, i have launch some hive query with Java program. But what i need is to execute a .hql with java

Comment: Do you want to call external **.hql** file through Java??

Comment: Yes, this is what i want to do